# Quadtree and size of region in constructor

Tags: c++, screen, sfml, bounds, quadtree

I was reading nice tutorial about Quadtree from
[this site](http://gamedev.tutsplus.com/tutorials/implementation/quick-tip-use-quadtrees-to-detect-likely-collisions-in-2d-space/)
and now is my question.

When I create quadtree I have to pass in constructor bounds of the screen, well What if my map's size 10000 x 10000px and game screen is 1280 x 720px, what should I pass?

```
Quadtree quad = new Quadtree(0, new Rectangle(0,0,600,600));
```

So in this example the screen region is just 600 x 600px. And it's working perfectly until player will go further than 600x600

I'm using c++ SFML 2.0, where sf::View is center to player position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the bounds of the whole map, regardless of whether parts of the region can be seen or not.